# Confusion with BeautifulSoup.find?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to grab the universities attorneys attended at a particular law firm, but I am unsure how to grab both universities listed in this link: https://www.wlrk.com/attorney/hahn/. As seen in the first linked image, the two universities this attorney attended are under the two seperate 'li' tags.

When I run the following code, I only get the html up to the end of the first 'li' tag (as seen in the second linked image), but not the second li section hence I only get the first university "Carleton College:"

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
url = 'https://www.wlrk.com/attorney/hahn/'
res = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0'})
personal_soup = soup(res.content, "html.parser")    
education = personal_soup.find("div",{'class':'attorney--education'})
education.li.a.text # 'Carleton University'
```

[html code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZcdp.png)
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0StV.png)

Comment: Not sure why bs is fetching both li elements. i have this working correctly using lxml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your parser and I would use `select` and target the `a` elements direct. 'lxml' is more forgiving and will handle the stray closing `a` tags which shouldn't be there. Also, `find` would only ever have returned first match versus `find_all` which returns all matches.

e.g.

`<a href="/attorneys/?asf_ugs=257">Carleton College</a></a>`

> Stray end tag a.
>
> From line 231, column 127; to line 231, column 130
>
> `ollege</a></a>, 2013`
>
> Stray end tag a.
>
> From line 231, column 239; to line 231, column 242
>
> `of Law</a></a>, J.D.`

[source](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.wlrk.com%2Fattorney%2Fhahn%2F)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

url = 'https://www.wlrk.com/attorney/hahn/'
res = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0'})
personal_soup = soup(res.content, "lxml")    
educations = [a.text for a in personal_soup.select('.attorney--education a')]
print(educations)
```

Comment: Does the select() function know "attorney--education" is part of the div tag? I am confused on why I would not have to put div in the selector. Also, this works and thanks for the help.

Comment: you could add the div in. Shorter selectors are generally better and class selectors are faster than tag + class. I examined the page and saw I didn't need to specify the tag (div) as well as class was sufficient to get the parent element. It is faster.

Answer (score 0):

The bs is fetching only the first li element. I am not sure why. If you want try using lxml, here is a way,

```
import lxml
from lxml import html


url = 'https://www.wlrk.com/attorney/hahn/'
res = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0'})

tree = html.fromstring(res.content)
education = tree.xpath("//div[@class='attorney--education']//li/a/text()")

print(education)
```

output:

> ['Carleton College', 'New York University School of Law']